# Android linearlayout same width as framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have the device in landscape mode and I have placed on it a `LinearLayout` which has inside a `FrameLayout`. This `FrameLayout` has inside a `VideoView` and the property `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.
Under the `FrameLayout` (and inside of the first `LinearLayout`) I want to put an other `LinearLayout` with some `ImaveView` and `TextView` inside.
The point is that the width of this second `LinearLayout` should be the same as the `FrameLayout`, which will have the size of its own content.

How could I do that? Any of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` or `android:layout_width="match_parent"` properties works properly.

Here is an example of my `.xml` code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="@color/yell"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >
        </VideoView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/videoplay"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="FullScreenVideo" >
        </Button>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/yell"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/usrimg"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/usrpicture" >
        </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `android:layout_width` property of your main layout (`LinearLayout`) to `wrap_content`.

This way, your main layout's width will fit the width of its childs. As the width of your second `LinearLayout` is set to fill_parent, only the width of the `FrameLayout` will be used.

**But**, as your main layout does not fit all the screen width, a default background (white) will be set for the empty space (the space where your main layout is not).

To avoid this, you can wrap all your layout in a `RelativeLayout` (or `LinearLayout` it does not matter), set the width of this layout to match_parent and set the background you want. So your layout will use all the screen space.

It will give you this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_background="{Your background}">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="@color/yell"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/videoView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/videoplay"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="FullScreenVideo" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/yell"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/usrimg"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/usrpicture" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

BTW, you should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` as it is deprecated.